# Месторасположение атрибута async в теге <script>

Tags: html

Более подробно:
 В теле html документа создавая внешний скрипт, чем вот такая запись

```
<script src="exemple_02.js" async></script>
```

Отличается от такой?

```
<script async src="exemple_02.js"></script>
```

Comment: Атрибут [async](https://webref.ru/html/script/async)

Comment: По выполнению — ничем.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что место расположения атрибута async перед или в конце ссылки значения не имеет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В спецификации w3c сказано что порядок следования аттрибутов не важен.

Это пункт 3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags, если захотите прочитать.

Comment: Вопрос стоял именно в лексической составляющей языка и правилах расположения элементов.

Comment: @OlegPpogiJ извиняюсь, не увидел async перед src во втором примере. Я немного отредактировал твой вопрос в заголовке, что бы он лучше отображался в поиске для будущих запросов, вопрос интересный.

Comment: Спасибо! Но думаю для  поиска сложновато построен заголовок. В идеале для ищущего(новичка) вид такой должен быть "Месторасположение атрибута async в теге <script>"